# TempDB default number of files in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, configuration, tempdb, sql-server-2016

Noticed the docs for SQL Server 2016 CTP2 state "by default, setup adds as many tempdb files as the CPU count or 8, whichever is lower."
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510411(v=sql.130).aspx

But I always thought that the "correct" ratio would be half the number of CPU cores, for boxes under 8 cores that is.

Should this be taken as the official recommandation from Microsoft and even applied to 2012/2014 ?

Comment: I think your initial assumption is incorrect https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2154845

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Paul Randal the number of tempdb files should be:

- equal to the number of CPU cores for 8 or less cores
- 1/4 to 1/2 of CPU cores for more than 8 cores

I think it's a great news that Microsoft finally changed this default setting. The previous one was really bad - it caused problems with latch contention.

[Paul Randal's article on the topic](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-1230-tempdb-should-always-have-one-data-file-per-processor-core/)

Answer (score 2):

While installing SQL Server 2016 you can now specify the number of tempDB data files. By default it will be set to 8 or the number of CPU cores you have in your machine, and which ever is lower. The value can also be increased up to the number of cores.

[image]
[**Source**](http://sqlwithmanoj.com/2015/05/29/installing-sql-server-2016-ctp2-and-new-features-in-ssms/)